# How to add a column with text values that is based on another column's numeric value

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
user <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
score <- c(10, 64, 45, 20, 67, 90, 33, 85, 23, 72)
df <- data.frame(user, score)
```

I would like to create another column (score_group column with only values "0-50","51-60","61-75","76-85","85-100") and automatically assign each row the correct group. Is this possible with R?

Comment: See `cut()` from base R